# How to autologin users after creating a new site (multisite)?

Tags: multisite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [User registration then auto login](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8998/user-registration-then-auto-login)

I am trying to create a fully customized multiuser site!
And i want users automatically login to their site after site creation...
Please help me..
Thank you...

Comment: I answered a similar question here:

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8998/user-registration-then-auto-login/10367#10367

Comment: A detailed blog: http://sforsuresh.in/auto-login-wordpress/

Answer (score 0):

I found this just a moment ago when searching. Works great.
http://blog.coderaustralia.com/tag/wordpress-auto-login-and-redirect