# Completely replacing the login form

Tags: login, single-sign-on

I need to completely replace WP's login form with the login form of an external service.

The actions and filters I've found (eg login_form, login_head) seem to rely on WP's login process starting. I suppose I could do a redirect from here, but is there a cleaner way of sending a user to another URL if they attempt to browse to a WordPress login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short and simple: No. You'll find a lot of stuff for wp-login.php on trac, but it seems that it won't change.

Comment: i'm thinking about just using the authenticate filter which seems to get called before the any login action takes place and controlling everything there.

Comment: Sound like a good plan.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working through how I'm doing this over on this question: [SSO / authentication integration with external 'directory service'](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8887/sso-authentication-integration-with-external-directory-service)

Answer (score 0):

In Wordpress 3.2 you can hook in `login_init` and redirect from there.