# Integrate Wordpress Blog with Moodle LMS

Tags: login

I would like to know if it is possible to integrate Wordpress and the Moodle LMS application? I would like the users to only sign in once to access both applications. I was hoping it will be possible to edit both application login processes to add whatever code is needed for both applications to create a cookie etc...
I'm already using one Database for authentication for both applications but this will just make it easier for the users. I'm not expecting a solution but just some advice from anyone if they think it will be possible.

Comment: Edwiser Bridge - WordPress Moodle LMS Integration https://wordpress.org/plugins/edwiser-bridge/

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely possible - I recently wrote a SSO plugin to allow users to be logged automatically into WP from a foreign system.

I sketched out my approach in this question: [SSO / authentication integration with external 'directory service'](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8887/sso-authentication-integration-with-external-directory-service)